# Should I ask what the starting pay is for a friend?

Tags: job-offer, hiring-process, human-resources, hiring, payroll

The company I work for is a start-up and is a fairly lax, scrappy environment. I have a friend in mind for a job opening here, but the shift is for 3pm-midnight. Our hiring team hasn't had much luck finding enough candidates for the position so my question is, is it appropriate for me to ask what the starting pay is for the position? I would communicate this to my friend to help him in his decision making.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, just be clear about your intentions. If they don't want to give out that information then it would be their responsibility to let you know. Otherwise, It's a very reasonable request.

> Hi HR,
>
> I have a friend who I think would be a good fit for *job opening
>   #12345*. What is the starting pay for that position?

Comment: Very reasonable.  You could even say, I need to know the pay band so that my friend can decide if it can even work or not.